# PHP / Bash : How do I run a shell script, passing a PHP variable where the script has "read" commands?

Tags: php, bash, shell, variables

I have a a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
echo -n "Enter the Name: "
read name
echo -n "Enter the age: "
read age

echo "$name is $age"
```

I have a PHP script that calls it:

How do I pass it the `name` and `age` parameters?  Note that I cannot modify the shell script itself!

Thanks!

Comment: if you can do it in bash you can do it in php

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP script, first create a temporary input file:

```
$ echo sharad > my_input_file
$ echo 20 >> my_input_file

#######################

$ cat my_input_file
sharad
20

#######################

$ cat my.sh
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
echo -n "Enter the Name: "
read name
echo -n "Enter the age: "
read age

echo "$name is $age"

#######################

$ cat my_input_file | ./my.sh
Enter the Name: Enter the age: sharad is 20

#######################
```

Comment: Is there a reason I couldn't do it like: `shell_exec("sudo printf 'sharad\n20' | ./my.sh");`?  When I try to run that it doesn't seem to be working, though....